# How to follow only Open Source projects on Kickstarter?

Tags: feeds, open-source, kickstarter

It seems that Kickstarter calls Open Source "[Open Software](http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/open%20software)".

How can I follow only these Open Software projects? I don't wish to invest in anything Closed Source.

Comment: What do you mean by "follow"? How do you want to follow it? Please explain.

Comment: I means something like RSS feed or mail notifications. I wish to get updates when new Open Source projects start a Kickstarter action

Answer (score 2):

You can track all new "Open Software" projects here:

http://www.kickspy.com/browse/new/open-software

There's no RSS option but you could can get the results emailed Daily or Weekly. Although if you want them Weekly I suggest using this list instead (since it shows all new projects over 7 days instead of 4 days in the browse list)

http://www.kickspy.com/projects/find?Keywords=&Status=0&Categories=50&TimeElapsedAtMost=7&SortBy=7&SortOrder=2

Hope that helps

**Update**

You can now subscribe to an RSS feed of all the results

Answer (score 1):

You can track open source projects by visiting the open source tag: http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/tags/open-source?ref=sidebar#p1

However, tracking via RSS does not work, at least not in Google Reader. There are RSS feed only for all projects or individual projects (see this link: http://www.kickstarter.com/help/faq/backer%20questions#ProfSett):

[image: RSS feeds for Kickstarter]

The notification settings in your account don't allow any specific tracking either:

[image]

You may be able to set up tracking changes with a software like [Website Watcher](http://www.aignes.com/). You can test in a 30-day trial if it works for you.

Apart from that, either wait & see or [send a suggestion to the Kickstarter team](http://kickstarter.zendesk.com/home).